# FindFirstBy JPA method returns Expected 1 but found 5 results error

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

In my entity there string field `cid` and date field `dt` along with other fields. Now I want to fetch one single row where `cid` matches and `dt` is the latest date. I tried with the following JPA method

```
Ret findFirstByCidOrderByDtDesc(String cid);
```

But I am getting the following error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Expected 1 but found 5 results; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected 1 but found 5 results
```

Isn't this JPA method supposed to provide single result? However if I replace `Ret` with `List' it works fine. How do I find the single result?

Answer (score 0):

change your method from :

```
Ret findFirstByCidOrderByDtDesc(String cid);
```

to :

```
Ret findTopByCidOrderByDtDesc(String cid);
```

Comment: Still getting the same error cause they are basically same method https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result

Comment: so you can use this : Ret findTop1ByCidOrderByDtDesc(String cid);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).